# NSButton highlight on mouse over and toggle state via click

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton

In Xcode, there is an 'In My Scope' button which highlights when you mouse over and stays highlighted until its 'unclicked'.

I can reproduce this via interface builder with the following:

[Xcode 'In My Scope'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwZ0L.png)

But I can't get this working via Code. This is what I've come up with:

```
scopeButton = [NSButton buttonWithTitle: @"In My Scope"
                                                   target: self
                                                   action: @selector(onScopeButton:)];
[scopeButton setButtonType: NSButtonTypeMomentaryLight];
scopeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
scopeButton.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyleRecessed;
scopeButton.bordered = YES;
```

And as far as I can tell, that matches the interface builder settings, but it works no where near the same. Any suggestions as to how I can get this to work via code?

Comment: That is just a text field for the title of the button.  You might want to edit your question to explain what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
scopeButton.bordered = YES;
```

by

```
scopeButton.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = YES;
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I couldn't figure this out from the xib so this was extremely helpful.